# Como passar uma variável PHP que está dentro de uma tag "a" para ser usado dentro de um Modal?

Tags: php, modal

Olá, sou novo em PHP e me deparei com um problema:
Como passar uma variável PHP ($id) que está dentro de uma tag "a" para dentro de um Modal?

Aqui está o código:

```
<?php
require '../SisCellCenter/autoloader.php';
use VisaoJR\Cellcenter\ClassPHP\Products;
$products = new Products();
?>

<div class="content">
    <div class="new-arrivals-w3agile">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- <h2 class="tittle">Destaques</h2> -->
            <?php
                $featuredProducts = $products->viewFeatureds();
                $rand_keys = array_rand($featuredProducts, sizeOf($featuredProducts)); //escolhe produtos em destaque aleatoriamente
                $max=0;
                if(sizeOf($featuredProducts)>9){$max = 9;} else{$max = sizeOf($featuredProducts);} //exibe no máximo 9 produtos em destaque
                for ($i=0; $i < $max; $i++) {
                ?>

                <div class="arrivals-grids">
                    <div class="col-md-3 arrival-grid simpleCart_shelfItem">
                        <div class="grid-arr">
                            <div  class="grid-arrival">
                                <figure>
                                    <a class="new-gri" id="featured" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#featuredModal" value="<?php $id = $i; ?>">
                                        <div class="grid-img">
                                            <?php echo '<img  src="images/Produtos/'.$featuredProducts[$rand_keys[$i]]->image.'">'; ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="grid-img">
                                            <?php echo '<img  src="images/Produtos/'.$featuredProducts[$rand_keys[$i]]->image.'">'; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </figure>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ribben">
                                <p>NEW</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ribben1">
                                <p>SALE</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="women">
                                <h6><center><?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[$i]]->name; ?></center></h6>
                                <span class="size"><?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[$i]]->brand; ?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <div class="clearfix"></div> -->
                </div>
            <?php }?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--content-->


<!--Modal produtos em destaque-->
<div class="modal fade" id="featuredModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content modal-info">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="news-gr">
                    <div class="col-md-5 new-grid1">
                        <?php echo '<img  src="images/Produtos/'.$featuredProducts[$id]->image.'" class="img-responsive" alt="">'; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 new-grid">
                        <h5><?php echo $featuredProducts[$id]->name; ?></h5>
                        <h6><?php echo $featuredProducts[$id]->brand; ?></h6>
                        <span><?php echo $featuredProducts[$id]->description; ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Desde já, agradeço a quem puder me ajudar!

Comment: Você tem que usar javascritp para resolver isso, não php.

Comment: E a tag <a> não tem o atributo value.

Comment: Pois @YurePereira, eu não consegui pensar em nada pra resolver isso. Digamos que eu sou bem novato nessa área

Comment: qual variável você esta querendo passar ?

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa resposta e veja se da para te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58958/passar-vari%C3%A1vel-php-para-javascript

Comment: Qual é a variável? `$id`? Em que lugar do modal você quer usa-la? Veja, Informações são tão importantes quanto códigos, tente colocar o máximo de informações e de forma clara para que as pessoas possam te ajudar. Abraço!

Comment: Sim, é a variável $id, pois com ela eu consigo acessar as informações do produto. ou então eu se puder eu gostaria de passar isso aqui: $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[$i]], que é o produto com todos os campos

Comment: Já usei também dessa forma: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129807/enviar-um-valor-para-o-modal

Comment: @Leo3102, mas aquela variável ela está em um loop, você vai querer todas as que puderem?

Comment: Ah ta... saquei... pera ae que vou formular a resposta

Answer (score 1):

Como passar valores do `PHP` para o `Javascript` e vice versa?

O que não pode ser ignorado no casamento de `Javascript` com `PHP` é que os dois estão rodando em extremos diferentes. Os scripts de `Javascript` com suas variáveis estão no browser, carregados juntamente com o `HTML`, e os scripts `PHP` terão executado suas tarefas do outro lado da `WEB`, lá no servidor.

A única via de comunicação entre eles são os textos `(html, javascript…)` que transitam no protocolo `HTTP`. Parece um paradoxo, uma vez que você encontrará `PHP`, `HTML` e `Javascript` no mesmo arquivo `index.php` (por exemplo). Porém, como dito anteriormente, cada um, `PHP` e Javascript atua em um ambiente diferente. Por exemplo:

Vamos supor o arquivo `teste.php` com o conteúdo abaixo:

```
<html>
   <body>
  <?php echo “Um Hello World !”; ?>
     </body>
</html>
<script type=”text/javascript”>
  alert(“Outro Hello World!”);
</script>
```

A parte que está colorida em cinza, é estática puramente texto em forma de tags `HTML`. A linha que está em vermelho corresponde a um programa em `PHP` para escrever “Hello World!”, que será interpretada pelo `PHP` no servidor, e somente o resultado será entregue ao Browser como segue:

```
<html>
  <body>
   Um Hello World!
  </body>
</html>
<script type=”text/javascript”>
  alert(“Outro Hello World!”);
</script>
```

Por último, a linha colorida em azul também não sofre modificações entre servidor e browser. Todavia o browser a interpretará como um comando para exibir uma pequena Janela com a frase `“Hello World”` e um botão de OK.

Até aí já dá pra perceber onde cada coisa está acontecendo.

Aproveitando se desta aparente reunião,vc pode construir o texto de um texto `Javascript` lá no servidor preenchendo o valor de uma variável `Javascript` usando `PHP:`

```
<html>
  <body>
  <?php echo “Um Hello World!”;
  $nome_individuo = “Cicrano de Mattos Pinto”;
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
<script type=”text/javascript”>
  var nome_individuo_1 = “Fulano”;
  var nome_individuo_2 = “<?php echo $nome_individuo; ?>“;
  alert(nome_individuo_1 + ”  ” + nome_individuo_2);
</script>
```

Como era de se esperar, o browser receberá o seguinte:

```
<html>
  <body>
   Um Hello World!
  </body>
</html>
<script type=”text/javascript”>
  var nome_individuo_1 = “Fulano”;
  var nome_individuo_2 = “Cicrano de Mattos Pinto”;
  alert(nome_individuo_1 + ”  ” + nome_individuo_2);
</script>
```

E pra transferir o valor de uma variável `PHP` para dentro de um arquivo `“.js”` ?

Então… não é possível fazer um `<? echo… ?>` dentro de um arquivo `“.js”,` porque normalmente isto só funciona dentro de um arquivo .php. Mas é perfeitamente possível um `<? echo… ?>` dentro de um arquivo `“.php”` da página `(index.php por exemplo…)` . Levemos em consideração que esta página também irá carregar arquivos `“.js”.`
Para isto basta criar variáveis (`Javascript`) globais (que podem ser do tipo `Array`), as quais podem ser denominadas “variáveis de ambiente”. Pois irão permitir o trânsito de informações do ambiente `HTML+PHP` para o âmbito do arquivo `Javascript`.

```
<script>
//para não criar muitas variáveis dispersas, é interessante criar um array de variáveis 
var VARS_AMBIENTE = new Array();
//em nosso exemplo vamos preencher a variável de ambiente “caminho_servidor”
// a qual terá seu conteúdo fornecido por um echo PHP
VARS_AMBIENTE[‘caminho_servidor’] = <? echo $caminho_server; ?>;
</script>
```

Reforçando que quando a página HTML + PHP for carregada no browser, o código acima será visto como:

```
<script>
var VARS_AMBIENTE = new Array();
VARS_AMBIENTE[‘caminho_servidor’] = “algum valor fornecido pelo echo do PHP lá no servidor…”;
</script>
```

Pois o `PHP` já terá feito seu trabalho no servidor quando a página for carregada no browser. E então o código do script que estiver no meio do `HTML` virá do servidor com a variável previamente preenchida.

Continuando a página `index.php…` agora basta carregar o script que deve ter alguma referência a `VARS_AMBIENTE[‘caminho_servidor’]` para receber o valor contido nesta variável:

```
<script src=“meuscript.js”></script>
```

Pronto! Qualquer código contido dentro de `meuscript.js` que faça referência a `VARS_AMBIENTE[‘caminho_servidor’]` terá acesso ao camino do servidor.

E o caminho inverso?

Já do javascript para o PHP, como cada um estará sendo interpretado em uma ponta diferente da web (Javascript – cliente / PHP – servidor), a única forma de enviar dados continua sendo através de tráfego pela rede. Nesta hora uma tag “mágica” pode ajudar:

```
<form …>

<input type=“hidden” id=“dados” name=“dados_enviar” value=“” />

</form>
```

```
<script>

//aqui a input hidden de id=”dados” recebe um valor dinâmicamente
//via código Javascript:

//cria um objeto de referência à tag input hidden
var objetoDados = document.getElementById(“dados”);
//altera o atributo value desta tag
objetoDados.value = “dados que vão para o servidor”;
</script>
```

No momento em que estes dados forem “submitados”, poderão ser adquiridos no servidor através de um script `PHP` que os capture via post por exemplo:

```
<?

echo $_POST[ ‘dados_enviar‘];

?>
```

Dica: Se vc copiar código para testar, reescreva as aspas duplas no editor de texto que vc estiver usando.

Pois o `WORDPRESS` coloca umas aspas mais estéticas que porém não são caracteres válidos nas engines `Javascript` e `PHP`.

[Fonte: https://ahaprogramando.wordpress.com/](https://ahaprogramando.wordpress.com/2008/01/19/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Para resgatar os valores que você utilizou em um `loop` anteriror, você deve salva-los em um conjunto de dados chamado `array`. =)

Então ficaria assim:

```
<?php 

    ... (codigo anterior) ...

    //declare o array antes do for
    $dados = array();

    $featuredProducts = $products->viewFeatureds();
    $rand_keys = array_rand($featuredProducts, sizeOf($featuredProducts)); //escolhe produtos em destaque aleatoriamente
    $max=0;
    if(sizeOf($featuredProducts)>9){$max = 9;} else{$max = sizeOf($featuredProducts);} //exibe no máximo 9 produtos em destaque
    for ($i=0; $i < $max; $i++) {

    $id = $i;
    $dados[] = $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[$i]]; // salva a variável ou então o id
    // $dados[] = $id; // aqui você usa o id se quiser

    ... (restante) ...

?>
```

Depois é só criar um outro loop e resgatar esses dados. Assim:

```
 <?php
for($i = 0; $i < count($dados); $i++){

?>
<!--Modal produtos em destaque-->
<div class="modal fade" id="featuredModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content modal-info">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="news-gr">
                    <div class="col-md-5 new-grid1">
                        <?php echo '<img  src="images/Produtos/'.$dados[$i]->image.'" class="img-responsive" alt="">'; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 new-grid">
                        <h5><?php echo $dados[$i]->name; ?></h5>
                        <h6><?php echo $dados[$i]->brand; ?></h6>
                        <span><?php echo $dados[$i]->description; ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Eu não fiz os testes, então pode ser que dê alguma coisa errada. Mas a lógica é essa.

Comment: Valeu pela dica, utilizei essa forma de usar o array $dados.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver de forma bem grotesca usando Java Script, segue o código modificado:

Se alguém conhece uma maneira de compactar este código eu agradeço e também fazer com que ao clicar na imagem seja como se estivesse clicando no input, pois do jeito que está fica exibindo o value=`<?php echo $i;?>`.

Agradeço ao @otaciojb pela explicação que ajudou bastante na compreensão do assunto Cliente/Server e aos outros colegas que se disponibilizaram a ajudar.

(OBs.: Está tudo dentro do mesmo arquivo!)

```
<?php
require '../SisCellCenter/autoloader.php';
use VisaoJR\Cellcenter\ClassPHP\Products;
$products = new Products();
$featuredProducts = $products->viewFeatureds();
$dados = array();
?>

<div class="content">
    <div class="new-arrivals-w3agile">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="tittle">Destaques</h2>
            <?php
                $rand_keys = array_rand($featuredProducts, sizeOf($featuredProducts)); //escolhe produtos em destaque aleatoriamente
                $max=0;
                if(sizeOf($featuredProducts)>9){$max = 9;} else{$max = sizeOf($featuredProducts);} //exibe no máximo 9 produtos em destaque
                for ($i=0; $i < $max; $i++) {
                // foreach ($featuredProducts as $fpValue):  //ainda não funciona pois os casos são estabelecidos manualmente no <script>!
            ?>
                <div class="arrivals-grids">
                    <div class="col-md-3 arrival-grid simpleCart_shelfItem">
                        <div class="grid-arr">
                            <div  class="grid-arrival">
                                <figure>
                                    <a href="#" class="new-gri" id="featured" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#featuredModal">
                                        <div class="grid-img">
                                            <?php
                                                $dados[] = $i; // salva o id para uso no Java Script
                                                echo '<img  src="images/Produtos/'.$featuredProducts[$rand_keys[$i]]->image.'">';
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="grid-img">
                                            <?php echo '<img  src="images/Produtos/'.$featuredProducts[$rand_keys[$i]]->image.'">';?>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $i;?>">
                                    </a>
                                </figure>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ribben">
                                <p>NEW</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ribben1">
                                <p>SALE</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="women">
                                <h6><center><?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[$i]]->name; ?></center></h6>
                                <span class="size"><?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[$i]]->brand; ?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php }
            // endforeach;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>







<div class="modal fade" id="featuredModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">';?>
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content modal-info">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id='leo' class="news-gr">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function(){
                        $("input").click(function(){
                            var valor = $(this).val();
                            if(valor == "<?php echo $rand_keys[0]?>"){
                                featuredClicked="<div class='col-md-5 new-grid1'>"+
                                        "<img  src='images/Produtos/<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[0]]->image; ?>' class='img-responsive' alt=''>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class='col-md-7 new-grid'>"+
                                        "<h5>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[0]]->name; ?>"+"</h5>"+
                                        "<h6>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[0]]->brand; ?>"+"</h6>"+
                                        "<span>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[0]]->description; ?>"+"</span>"+
                                        "<div class='color-quality'>"+
                                        "<div class='color-quality-left'>"+
                                        "<h6>Cores:</h6>"+
                                        "olors_idcolors do banco de dados= "+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[0]]->colors_idcolors; ?>"+
                                        "<ul>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#'><span></span>Red</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='brown'><span></span>Yellow</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='purple'><span></span>Purple</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='gray'><span></span>Violet</a></li>"+
                                        "</ul>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class='clearfix'> </div>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "</div>";
                                document.getElementById('leo').innerHTML=featuredClicked;
                            }
                            else if(valor == "<?php echo $rand_keys[1]?>"){
                                featuredClicked="<div class='col-md-5 new-grid1'>"+
                                        "<img  src='images/Produtos/<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[1]]->image; ?>' class='img-responsive' alt=''>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class='col-md-7 new-grid'>"+
                                        "<h5>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[1]]->name; ?>"+"</h5>"+
                                        "<h6>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[1]]->brand; ?>"+"</h6>"+
                                        "<span>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[1]]->description; ?>"+"</span>"+
                                        "<div class='color-quality'>"+
                                        "<div class='color-quality-left'>"+
                                        "<h6>Cores:</h6>"+
                                        "olors_idcolors do banco de dados= "+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[1]]->colors_idcolors; ?>"+
                                        "<ul>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#'><span></span>Red</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='brown'><span></span>Yellow</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='purple'><span></span>Purple</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='gray'><span></span>Violet</a></li>"+
                                        "</ul>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class='clearfix'> </div>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "</div>";
                                document.getElementById('leo').innerHTML=featuredClicked;
                            }
                            else if(valor == "<?php echo $rand_keys[2]?>"){
                                featuredClicked="<div class='col-md-5 new-grid1'>"+
                                        "<img  src='images/Produtos/<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[2]]->image; ?>' class='img-responsive' alt=''>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class='col-md-7 new-grid'>"+
                                        "<h5>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[2]]->name; ?>"+"</h5>"+
                                        "<h6>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[2]]->brand; ?>"+"</h6>"+
                                        "<span>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[2]]->description; ?>"+"</span>"+
                                        "<div class='color-quality'>"+
                                        "<div class='color-quality-left'>"+
                                        "<h6>Cores:</h6>"+
                                        "olors_idcolors do banco de dados= "+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[2]]->colors_idcolors; ?>"+
                                        "<ul>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#'><span></span>Red</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='brown'><span></span>Yellow</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='purple'><span></span>Purple</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='gray'><span></span>Violet</a></li>"+
                                        "</ul>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class='clearfix'> </div>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "</div>";
                                document.getElementById('leo').innerHTML=featuredClicked;
                            }
                            else if(valor == "<?php echo $rand_keys[3]?>"){
                                featuredClicked="<div class='col-md-5 new-grid1'>"+
                                        "<img  src='images/Produtos/<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[3]]->image; ?>' class='img-responsive' alt=''>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class='col-md-7 new-grid'>"+
                                        "<h5>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[3]]->name; ?>"+"</h5>"+
                                        "<h6>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[3]]->brand; ?>"+"</h6>"+
                                        "<span>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[3]]->description; ?>"+"</span>"+
                                        "<div class='color-quality'>"+
                                        "<div class='color-quality-left'>"+
                                        "<h6>Cores:</h6>"+
                                        "olors_idcolors do banco de dados= "+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[3]]->colors_idcolors; ?>"+
                                        "<ul>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#'><span></span>Red</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='brown'><span></span>Yellow</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='purple'><span></span>Purple</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='gray'><span></span>Violet</a></li>"+
                                        "</ul>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class='clearfix'> </div>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "</div>";
                                document.getElementById('leo').innerHTML=featuredClicked;
                            }
                            else if(valor == "<?php echo $rand_keys[4]?>"){
                                featuredClicked="<div class='col-md-5 new-grid1'>"+
                                        "<img  src='images/Produtos/<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[4]]->image; ?>' class='img-responsive' alt=''>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class='col-md-7 new-grid'>"+
                                        "<h5>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[4]]->name; ?>"+"</h5>"+
                                        "<h6>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[4]]->brand; ?>"+"</h6>"+
                                        "<span>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[4]]->description; ?>"+"</span>"+
                                        "<div class='color-quality'>"+
                                        "<div class='color-quality-left'>"+
                                        "<h6>Cores:</h6>"+
                                        "olors_idcolors do banco de dados= "+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[4]]->colors_idcolors; ?>"+
                                        "<ul>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#'><span></span>Red</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='brown'><span></span>Yellow</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='purple'><span></span>Purple</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='gray'><span></span>Violet</a></li>"+
                                        "</ul>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class='clearfix'> </div>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "</div>";
                                document.getElementById('leo').innerHTML=featuredClicked;
                            }
                            else if(valor == "<?php echo $rand_keys[5]?>"){
                                featuredClicked="<div class='col-md-5 new-grid1'>"+
                                        "<img  src='images/Produtos/<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[5]]->image; ?>' class='img-responsive' alt=''>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class='col-md-7 new-grid'>"+
                                        "<h5>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[5]]->name; ?>"+"</h5>"+
                                        "<h6>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[5]]->brand; ?>"+"</h6>"+
                                        "<span>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[5]]->description; ?>"+"</span>"+
                                        "<div class='color-quality'>"+
                                        "<div class='color-quality-left'>"+
                                        "<h6>Cores:</h6>"+
                                        "olors_idcolors do banco de dados= "+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[5]]->colors_idcolors; ?>"+
                                        "<ul>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#'><span></span>Red</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='brown'><span></span>Yellow</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='purple'><span></span>Purple</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='gray'><span></span>Violet</a></li>"+
                                        "</ul>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class='clearfix'> </div>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "</div>";
                                document.getElementById('leo').innerHTML=featuredClicked;
                            }
                            else if(valor == "<?php echo $rand_keys[6]?>"){
                                featuredClicked="<div class='col-md-5 new-grid1'>"+
                                        "<img  src='images/Produtos/<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[6]]->image; ?>' class='img-responsive' alt=''>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class='col-md-7 new-grid'>"+
                                        "<h5>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[6]]->name; ?>"+"</h5>"+
                                        "<h6>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[6]]->brand; ?>"+"</h6>"+
                                        "<span>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[6]]->description; ?>"+"</span>"+
                                        "<div class='color-quality'>"+
                                        "<div class='color-quality-left'>"+
                                        "<h6>Cores:</h6>"+
                                        "olors_idcolors do banco de dados= "+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[6]]->colors_idcolors; ?>"+
                                        "<ul>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#'><span></span>Red</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='brown'><span></span>Yellow</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='purple'><span></span>Purple</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='gray'><span></span>Violet</a></li>"+
                                        "</ul>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class='clearfix'> </div>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "</div>";
                                document.getElementById('leo').innerHTML=featuredClicked;
                            }
                            else if(valor == "<?php echo $rand_keys[7]?>"){
                                featuredClicked="<div class='col-md-5 new-grid1'>"+
                                        "<img  src='images/Produtos/<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[7]]->image; ?>' class='img-responsive' alt=''>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class='col-md-7 new-grid'>"+
                                        "<h5>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[7]]->name; ?>"+"</h5>"+
                                        "<h6>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[7]]->brand; ?>"+"</h6>"+
                                        "<span>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[7]]->description; ?>"+"</span>"+
                                        "<div class='color-quality'>"+
                                        "<div class='color-quality-left'>"+
                                        "<h6>Cores:</h6>"+
                                        "olors_idcolors do banco de dados= "+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[7]]->colors_idcolors; ?>"+
                                        "<ul>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#'><span></span>Red</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='brown'><span></span>Yellow</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='purple'><span></span>Purple</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='gray'><span></span>Violet</a></li>"+
                                        "</ul>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class='clearfix'> </div>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "</div>";
                                document.getElementById('leo').innerHTML=featuredClicked;
                            }
                            else if(valor == "<?php echo $rand_keys[8]?>"){
                                featuredClicked="<div class='col-md-5 new-grid1'>"+
                                        "<img  src='images/Produtos/<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[8]]->image; ?>' class='img-responsive' alt=''>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class='col-md-7 new-grid'>"+
                                        "<h5>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[8]]->name; ?>"+"</h5>"+
                                        "<h6>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[8]]->brand; ?>"+"</h6>"+
                                        "<span>"+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[8]]->description; ?>"+"</span>"+
                                        "<div class='color-quality'>"+
                                        "<div class='color-quality-left'>"+
                                        "<h6>Cores:</h6>"+
                                        "olors_idcolors do banco de dados= "+"<?php echo $featuredProducts[$rand_keys[8]]->colors_idcolors; ?>"+
                                        "<ul>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#'><span></span>Red</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='brown'><span></span>Yellow</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='purple'><span></span>Purple</a></li>"+
                                        "<li><a href='#' class='gray'><span></span>Violet</a></li>"+
                                        "</ul>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class='clearfix'> </div>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "</div>";
                                document.getElementById('leo').innerHTML=featuredClicked;
                            }
                            else {
                                alert("Botão Salvar e Sair");
                            }
                        });

                    });
                    </script>

                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```